# list all fields in a DB and how often then appear - SQLite 3

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

In SQLite 3, I'd like to build a piece of SQL (or otherwise - as long as I can execute it with a basic SQLiteStudio install for example) that can read from all the tables in a given db, and list their fields and how many times they appear across all the tables (based on their names).

example:

First table: Person

Fields:

1. PersonID
2. First Name
3. Last Name

Second table: Address

Fields:

1. PersonID
2. Street

After running the code I'd have a third table called, for example, fields_list, like such:

Field:    /    Count:

PersonID    /    2

First Name   /   1

Last Name    /   1

Street     /     1

Any idea?
I'm ok with pure SQL but this sort of looping through the tables themselves is way above what I can do I'm afraid...

thanks in advance!

Andre

Comment: This is not possible in pure SQL. SQLite is an embedded database that is intended to be used together with a real programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little bit of scripting. Suppose my database structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE a (personID text, name text);
CREATE TABLE b (personID text, address text);
```

the following shell command will aggregate column names by count (replace foo.sqlite with your database file):

```
sqlite3 foo.sqlite "select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'" | while read tableName; do sqlite3 foo.sqlite "pragma table_info($tableName)"; done | awk -F\| '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

giving the output:

```
   1 address
   1 name
   2 personID
```

Here is a step by step break-down of what it is doing:

Print the names of all tables - one per line

```
sqlite3 foo.sqlite "select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'"

Output
a
b
```

Read each table name, and execute `PRAGMA table_name()` to print out the table schema:

```
while read tableName; do sqlite3 foo.sqlite "pragma table_info($tableName)"; done

Output
0|personID|text|0||0
1|name|text|0||0
0|personID|text|0||0
1|address|text|0||0
```

Use `|` as the delimiter and grab the second column:

```
awk -F\| '{print $2}'

Output
personID
name
personID
address
```

Sort the results:

```
sort

Output
address
name
personID
personID
```

Merge unique results, and -c displays the count of how many items something appeared.

```
uniq -c

Output
   1 address
   1 name
   2 personID
```